# NPM not available outside root when installing node via snap

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-22.04, snap

I just installed node on Ubuntu 22.04 via snap using the following command, per GitHub page instructions:

```
# snap install node --classic
```

Afterwards, node and npm both reported their versions successfully.

```
# node --version
v18.16.0
# npm --version
9.5.1
```

As soon as I drop out of root though, only node remains available to me as a non-privileged user:

```
$ node --version
v18.16.0
$ npm --version
-bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

Is this expected behaviour? How can I make npm available generally?

For what its worth, here is the content of /snap/bin:

```
$ ls -l /snap/bin
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 04:51 amazon-ssm-agent.ssm-cli -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7 Jun  1 04:51 lxc -> lxd.lxc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 04:51 lxd -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 04:51 lxd.benchmark -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 04:51 lxd.buginfo -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 04:51 lxd.check-kernel -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 04:51 lxd.lxc -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 04:51 lxd.lxc-to-lxd -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 04:51 lxd.migrate -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 11:52 node -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 11:52 node.npm -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 11:52 node.npx -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 11:52 node.yarn -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun  1 11:52 node.yarnpkg -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8 Jun  1 11:52 npm -> node.npm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8 Jun  1 11:52 npx -> node.npx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jun  1 04:51 ssm-cli -> amazon-ssm-agent.ssm-cli
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun  1 11:52 yarn -> node.yarn
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jun  1 11:52 yarnpkg -> node.yarnpkg
```

Note that the `nodejs` and `npm` packages were previously installed but then removed via `apt` before trying to use snap. Perhaps some hangover from that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue.

TL;DR : I removed node snap package (which removes npm snap package too) and installed `nvm`, then `nvm install node`. Everything works like a charm.

To get into the details, I think it would also work to change PATH but I'm not sure it is a recommended way to fix this issue.
[nvm installation procedure is pretty straightforward](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34656388)